# testing sed with symbol ^

Tags: sed

I tested sed:

```
rsa@rsa-VirtualBox:~$ echo GreenTea | sed 's/Green/Red/'
RedTea
rsa@rsa-VirtualBox:~$ echo GreenTea | sed 's/^Green/Red/'
RedTea
```

What's the meaning ^ here?

In my understanding, ^ means not include, but it can't explain the result above.

Comment: That is called anchor , It if used like what you have posted it means the start of the word/pattern, it has a different meaning if it is the first character inside the `[ ]`, READ `man 7 regex` on your local manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provided examples `^` means starts with.

```
echo GreenTea | sed 's/^Green/Red/'
```

It means check with line which starts with `Green` and substitute Green with `Red` here.